# How to change line numbers background in Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: dreamweaver

Does anybody have an idea how to get rid of line numbers blue background?
It's quite distracting :(
Maybe there is some extension for deeper customization of Dreamweaver (CS5) ?
Even here: [Tom’s dark DW dark code colorization for Dreamweaver](http://www.sramekdesign.com/dreamweaver/dark-coding-colorization-for-dreamweaver/) it's still blue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to change it.  The line number bar is a hardcoded object and none of the CSS files or XML files affect it.

Comment: Long time havn't been here :) Thanks for an answer! Currently Sublime Text 2 is my friend.

Comment: Heh.  I'm using Programmer's Notepad more and more these days.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to change it.
By affecting the basic operation system's settings for the active line highlight color
 it's possible to achieve this effect.

It probably works on all windows platforms:
for this demonstration I ll explain how to do it on win7.
1. right click on the screen
2. choose personalize
3. window color / advanced appearance settings  
4. choose 'selected items' from the drop-down menu
5. modify 'color1' to the color u wish to use in DW.

and its all done. DW inherits the operating system's default/modified color settings. 

cheers, Nel.